# Python: use a dict with lambda functions when using .format() on a string

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

The setting is: I have a dict (format_dict), and in that dict there are lambda functions. If I want to read from the dict normally, it does not work like this:

```py
    dict = {
    'name_U':  (lambda: name.upper()),
    'name_L':  (lambda: name.lower()),
    'name_fL': (lambda: name[0])
    }
    name = 'John'
    print(dict['name_U'])
```

because it returns:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x00000000E1F45012>
```

But if I instead do `print(dict['name_U']())`, it works as intended (printing `JOHN`).

The problem comes when I want to use this dict to format a string. If it is like this:

```py
    print('My name in uppercase is {name_U}. The first letter is {name_fL}.'.format(**dict))
```

it returns

```
My name in uppercase is <function <lambda> at 0x00000000E1F45012>. The first letter is <function <lambda> at 0x00000000E1F46123>.
```

(where I would want the output to be `My name in uppercase is JOHN. The first letter is J.`)

If i try what i did in the 'normal' case (`...format(**dict()))`), it returns an error, saying `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`. Is there any way to circumvent this?

On a side note: I can't use the dict as

```py
    dict = {
    'name_U':  name.upper(),
    'name_L':  name.lower(),
    'name_fL': name[0]
    }
```

because then the values of the dict will be the same after the assignment, even if `name` changes value.

Comment: `print(f'my name in uppercase is {dict["name_U"]()}. The first letter is {dict["name_fL"]()}') -->
my name in uppercase is JOHN. The first letter is J`

Answer (score 0):

```
dct = {
'name_U':  (lambda: name.upper()),
'name_L':  (lambda: name.lower()),
'name_fL': (lambda: name[0])
}

name = 'John'

print('my name in uppercase is {name_U}. The first letter is {name_fL}.'.format(**{k: v() for k, v in dct.items()}))
```

Prints:

```
my name in uppercase is JOHN. The first letter is J.
```

---

Or use f-strings, like in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `f-strings`.

```
In [57]: dict = {
    ...: 'name_U':  (lambda: name.upper()),
    ...: 'name_L':  (lambda: name.lower()),
    ...: 'name_fL': (lambda: name[0])
    ...: }

In [58]:

In [58]: print(f'my name in uppercase is {dict["name_U"]()}. The first letter is {dict["name_fL"]()}')
my name in uppercase is JOHN. The first letter is J
```